# Getting a Folder ID C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to track a files and folders through their lifetime (they may be moved or renamed). I have done searching and found that [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) might be the most popular way to track files and folders, however, this will not work for me as the application may or may not be always running. I have chosen to try to track the folders via an ID.

I have found a way to track files from an ID from the answer to [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866547/2352808). I can successfully grab file IDs based on Approach B in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866788/2352808).

While searching I found [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10132686/2352808) stating he found his solution using [FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa364570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to use this function, but I can not wrap my head around it. I have essentially zero experience calling native windows functions from within C#.

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction for this? I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Is there a reason C# can't access file/folder IDs? Is tracking files/folders uncommon?

Edit, adding code:

```
        static uint returnVal;

    //Working example to get File ID
    public static string GetFileId(string path)
    {
        WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION objectFileInfo = new WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
        FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        WinAPI.GetFileInformationByHandle(fs.Handle, out objectFileInfo);

        fs.Close();

        ulong fileIndex = ((ulong)objectFileInfo.FileIndexHigh << 32) + (ulong)objectFileInfo.FileIndexLow;

        return fileIndex.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetFolderId(string path)
    {
        //Get a handle on the given folder
        IntPtr cFile = WinAPI.CreateFile(
            path,
            WinAPI.GENERIC_READ,
            FileShare.Read,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (FileMode)WinAPI.OPEN_EXISTING,
            WinAPI.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        Console.WriteLine(path);
        Console.WriteLine(cFile);

        if ((int)cFile != -1)
        {
            int cFileSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
            Console.WriteLine("cFile size = {0}", cFileSize);

            IntPtr cFileBlob = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cFileSize);
            uint numBytesRead = 0;

            WinAPI.DeviceIoControl(cFile, WinAPI.FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID, IntPtr.Zero, 0, cFileBlob, (uint)cFileSize, ref numBytesRead, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (returnVal == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); // Returning error 87 here
            }
        }

        //Should be returning the ID from the folder.
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(GetFileId(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\TestDocument.txt"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetFolderId(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop"));
    }

}

class WinAPI
{
    // Win32 constants for accessing files.
    internal const int GENERIC_READ = unchecked((int)0x80000000);
    internal const int FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = unchecked((int)0x02000000);
    internal const int OPEN_EXISTING = unchecked((int)3);
    internal const int FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID = 0x0009009c;
    internal const int FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID = 0x000900c0;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint dwIoControlCode, IntPtr lpInBuffer, uint nInBufferSize, [Out] IntPtr lpOutBuffer, uint nOutBufferSize, ref uint lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(IntPtr hFile, out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
       String fileName,
       int dwDesiredAccess,
       System.IO.FileShare dwShareMode,
       IntPtr securityAttrs_MustBeZero,
       System.IO.FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
       int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
       IntPtr hTemplateFile_MustBeZero);

    public struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
    {
        public uint FileAttributes;
        public FILETIME CreationTime;
        public FILETIME LastAccessTime;
        public FILETIME LastWriteTime;
        public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
        public uint FileSizeHigh;
        public uint FileSizeLow;
        public uint NumberOfLinks;
        public uint FileIndexHigh;
        public uint FileIndexLow;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error "87" back from DeviceIoControl, which is invalid parameter according to a post on MSDN (I am unable to post more links due to reputation restrictions.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This is a feature for upscale servers, clusters with automatic fail-over.  It isn't going to work on the C: drive of your dev machine.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you elaborate, please? It worked for the people in the sources he linked and nothing in the API description as far as I can see indicates that it would not work on the desktop.

Comment: @HansPassant, how will this not work for general use? Is there another approach I can take to get these IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you got no problem with `FileSystemWatcher`. So, for how to use `DeviceIoControl` in C#, have a look of this answer:

[Physical disk size not correct (IoCtlDiskGetDriveGeometry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051660/physical-disk-size-not-correct-ioctldiskgetdrivegeometry/15073586#15073586)

To this question, it's done with the following code:

```
class Program {
    const uint FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID=0x0009009c;

    public static String GetFileId(String path) {
        using(var fs=File.Open(
            path, 
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            ) {
            WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION info;
            WinAPI.GetFileInformationByHandle(fs.Handle, out info);
            return String.Format(
                    "{0:x}", ((info.FileIndexHigh<<32)|info.FileIndexLow));
        }
    }

    public static WinAPI.FILE_OBJECTID_BUFFER GetFolderIdBuffer(String path) {
        using(var hFile=WinAPI.CreateFile(
            path,
            WinAPI.GENERIC_READ, FileShare.Read,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (FileMode)WinAPI.OPEN_EXISTING,
            WinAPI.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            IntPtr.Zero
            )) {
            if(null==hFile||hFile.IsInvalid)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            var buffer=default(WinAPI.FILE_OBJECTID_BUFFER);
            var nOutBufferSize=Marshal.SizeOf(buffer);
            var lpOutBuffer=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nOutBufferSize);
            var lpBytesReturned=default(uint);

            var result=
                WinAPI.DeviceIoControl(
                    hFile, FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID,
                    IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                    lpOutBuffer, nOutBufferSize,
                    ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero
                    );

            if(!result)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            var type=typeof(WinAPI.FILE_OBJECTID_BUFFER);

            buffer=(WinAPI.FILE_OBJECTID_BUFFER)
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(lpOutBuffer, type);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpOutBuffer);
            return buffer;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(
            GetFileId(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\TestDocument.txt"));

        var buffer=GetFolderIdBuffer(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop");

        var objectId=buffer.ObjectId
                .Reverse()
                .Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))
                .Aggregate(String.Concat);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", objectId);
    }
}

class WinAPI {
    internal const int
        GENERIC_READ=unchecked((int)0x80000000),
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS=unchecked((int)0x02000000),
        OPEN_EXISTING=unchecked((int)3);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FILE_OBJECTID_BUFFER {
        public struct Union {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
            public byte[] BirthVolumeId;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
            public byte[] BirthObjectId;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
            public byte[] DomainId;
        }

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
        public byte[] ObjectId;

        public Union BirthInfo;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=48)]
        public byte[] ExtendedInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION {
        public uint FileAttributes;
        public FILETIME CreationTime;
        public FILETIME LastAccessTime;
        public FILETIME LastWriteTime;
        public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
        public uint FileSizeHigh;
        public uint FileSizeLow;
        public uint NumberOfLinks;
        public uint FileIndexHigh;
        public uint FileIndexLow;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
        SafeFileHandle hDevice,
        uint dwIoControlCode,
        IntPtr lpInBuffer,
        uint nInBufferSize,
        [Out] IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
        int nOutBufferSize,
        ref uint lpBytesReturned,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        String fileName,
        int dwDesiredAccess,
        System.IO.FileShare dwShareMode,
        IntPtr securityAttrs_MustBeZero,
        System.IO.FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
        int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile_MustBeZero
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(
        IntPtr hFile, out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);
}
```

The name space is required of using:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
```

Comment: Added the code I have so far. I am able to retrieve an I for files, but I am coming up completely blank for calling DeviceIoControl.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read it. I've updated it with some progress.

Comment: This is exactly what I was working for all day Ken, thank you very much!

Comment: I think BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION should be declared 
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]

Comment: @chha: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.ASPX

Comment: Hi. Do you have any idea why the code breaks at the "var result = WinAPI.DeviceIoControl(..." line, in the GetFolderId methid. Result always returns FALSE, no matter what folder path I set as a parameter.

Comment: @relysis: Then it should throw an exception with the error code. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you are getting error 2 then replace get object id to line const uint  FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID = 0x000900C0;

Comment: When path contains unicode character,  the getfolderidbuffer returns error 'the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect'. Any solution?

Comment: Ok got solution for unicode as well. Just simply add CharSet = CharSet.Auto in DllImpprt(kernel32.dll)